# Oracle APEX Data Loading 3 Primary Keys Limit

Tags: oracle, primary-key, oracle-apex

At APEX's "Create Data Load Wizard", only 3 primary keys can be set. I'm looking for a way to use the Data Loading screen  with a 4-primary-key table.

Comment: I think you'll be struggling. Perhaps consider the excel2collection plugin, and use you own PL/SQL for transformation

Comment: Agreed with Scott. Another approach to consider is to use the wizard just to load into a scratch table, then write your own custom SQL to do the data matching and merge into your target table.